# Ansible/Jinja2 asterisk conditional

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Trying to update a LDAP entry via Ansible, but I want to make sure that the LDAP host wildcard ("*") is not in the host list. If I use `"*" not in hosts` or `'*' not in hosts`, Ansible does not like those. I've also tried Jinja2 search filters. Any help would be great!

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you're asking. Try posting snippets from your playbook.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the asterisk. It is a pure yaml syntax problem

In yaml, if you quote a variable, the representation of the value will start with a single or double quote, then you get the value itself and the closing quote. After that, the yaml parser is expecting a yank `<block end>`, in your specific case a new line to move on to the next value definition.

In your example, your `when` clause value starts with a quote. So you have to quote your entire value:

```yaml
when: '"*" not in hosts'
# or
when: "'*' not in hosts"
# even
when: "\"*\" not in hosts"
```

A good and more readable alternative IMO is to use a yaml scalar block marker:

```yaml
when: >-
  "*" not in hosts
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured this out. Was trying to do it with pipes and didn't need to.

```
when:
  - var is not regex("\\*")
```